# Far manager 3, PanelTabs plugin: how to switch between tabs?

Tags: far-manager

The help for PanelTabs plugin is in russian, I don't get how to switch between tabs.

If someone that use this plugin can help me. Maybe I have to assign every tab to a folder shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Switching tabs

There is no default shortcut to change between the tabs of the [PanelTabs plugin](https://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=873&l=en) but you can assign one (see third bullet point below).

You can change between tabs by doing one of the following:

- Clicking on the tab names (Press `Ctrl+UP` to minimize the panels if you don't see the tab names)
- OR go to `Plugins(F11) -> Panel Tabs -> Select Tab -> Press 1/2/3...`
- OR **assign a keyboard shortcut** for Select Tab

  - Install the [`MacroLib` plugin](https://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=844)
  - Create the folder **`Macros`** in the `MacroLib` folder (`C:\Program Files\Far Manager\Plugins\MacroLib\Macros`)
  - Copy **`PanelTabs.fmlua`** to the created `Macros` folder. Example:

    - source: `C:\Program Files\Far Manager\Plugins\PanelTabs\PanelTabs.fmlua`
    - destination: `C:\Program Files\Far Manager\Plugins\MacroLib\Macros\PanelTabs.fmlua`
  - Restart FAR Manager
  - You should be able now to press **Right-Ctrl, 2** to select the second tab. Pay attention that you press the digit (e.g. 2) after you depress the Right Control, not simultaneously. The shortcut for `SelectTabs` is defined in the PanelTabs.fmlua file (`Bind="RCtrl:Release"`)
- Execute **`tab:/edit`** at the command line and select the tab (or edit it, maybe to lock it)

---

## Documentation

Some Google translated documentation from the original russin `PanelTabs plugin` documentation:

### PanelTabs - Bookmarks for FAR Manager panels (Plugin created by Maxim Rusov)

The plugin adds a row of bookmarks to the FAR panels, which can be switched by mouse or keyboard. To make the tabs visible you should reduce the height of the panels by at least one line (`Ctrl + Up`)

Two types of bookmarks are supported:

- **Non-fixed bookmarks** - Bookmarks of this type automatically monitor the change of the current directory in the FAR panel
- **Fixed bookmarks** - Bookmarks of this type store the directory at the time of adding, and allow you to return to it later with a single mouse click. In fact, they are a visual analogue of Folder Shortcuts.

  Also, fixed bookmarks can be used to run macros or programs, thus being a kind of analog toolbar.

### Keyboard control

To switch bookmarks from the keyboard, you can assign macros to the Select tab command from the main menu of the plugin. On this command the plug-in goes into the bookmark selection mode. The choice is made by additional pressing of digital or the letter key corresponding to the bookmark number.

In addition, in the bookmark selection mode, the following commands are available:

- `Ins` - Add bookmark
- `Del` - Delete bookmark
- `Space` - Open Bookmark List
- `Mul` - Change the bookmark type (fixed / non-fixed)
- `Tab` - The following command will apply to the tab on the passive panel (it makes sense only for separate bookmarks)
- `Div` - The next bookmark selection command will be executed on the opposite panel
- `Esc` - Exit bookmarks selection mode

The prefix `Tab` and `Div` keys can be part of the calling macro.

### Bookmark list

Displays a list of bookmarks for one FAR panel and allows you to edit it. The dialog can be accessed through the plugin menu or by right-clicking on the bookmark adding button ("+").

Keyboard combinations:

- `Enter` - Select current bookmark

  The same action is performed on the left mouse click
- `F4` - Edit bookmark.

  The same action is performed with the right mouse click
- `Ins` Add bookmark
- `Del` Delete Bookmark
- `Ctrl-Up` Move bookmark up
- `Ctrl-Down` Move bookmark down

### Prefix `Tab:`

The plugin adds the prefix `Tab:` (case insensitive), through which the basic commands for managing bookmarks are available.

Tab: without parameters - call the main menu of the plugin. `(Does this work??)`

After the prefix Tab: you can specify a number of commands. All commands start with "/" or "-":

- `tab:/Add` - Add the current folder to the bookmark list
- `tab:/Edit` - Open Bookmark List
- `tab:/Save=FileName` - Save the current list of bookmarks to a file
- `tab:/Load=FileName` - Load the current list of bookmarks from the file